# Keep Data From (Multiple)Textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm New in .Net MVC4 and i have some problem....

Example : In view i have 2 textbox

```
<input type="text" name="tax1" style="width:20px" maxlength="1" /> 
<input type="text" name="tax2" style="width:60px" maxlength="4" />
```

After I push Submit Button I want to keep both data from textbox.

```
Ex : string value = textbox1 + textbox2
```

Can I do my Requirement following this Example(in View).

If OK : Please tell me about Solution.

of If not OK : Please tell me about Solution and Which File to Resolve its(ex.controller, etc.).

Comment: You whant to keep this textbox value in Controller?

Comment: Can i keep this value in View?

Comment: You want to `post` your page to `controller` or you just keep this `textbox` value in your `view` page.

Comment: Now. I can Resolve my problem.
Thannk You Every One for Help me ^^

Comment: I define this temporality value in Model.
and I Declare temporality value for keep data from textbox in View.

in Controller : string value = model.temp1 + model.temp2 + ...

Answer (score 0):

You have a form similar to the following in your View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="tax1" style="width:20px" maxlength="1" /> 
    <input type="text" name="tax2" style="width:60px" maxlength="4" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string tax1, string tax2)
{
    string newString = tax1 + tax2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. One way is that of `mostruash`. I normally bind my view to a `view model`. I never do it any other way. I never use properties or the domain model, only a view model. I will show you how.

Your view model could look like this:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
     public string Tax1 { get; set; }

     public string Tax2 { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your action method you need to pass it to your view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
     SomeViewModel viewModel = new SomeViewModel();

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

And in your post action method you need to receive this view model as an input paramter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeViewModel viewModel)
{
     // Check for null viewModel

     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          return View(viewModel);
     }

     // Do what ever else you need to do
}
```

And then on your view:

```
@model SomeProject.ViewModels.Servers.SomeViewModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Tax1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Tax2)
```

I hope this helps.